# Twitter sign in crashes with TWTRInvalidInitializationException

Tags: ios, swift, twitter

My app crashes when i try to login with twitter, with an error message

**Attempt made to Log in or Like a Tweet without a valid Twitter Kit URL Scheme set up in the app settings. Please see https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/installation for more info.**

I have applied twitter login using fabric.But after converting my code from swift 2.3 to swift 3, it started crashing.I have updated my pods too and reapplied the steps for sign in again without fabric, as fabric is not showing the twitter option now. But still the crash remains.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If i understand correctly you have used Twitter with Fabric, so i assume you had something like this in your AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    Fabric.with([Twitter.self])    
    return true
}
```

Note that since Google acquired Fabric you should use:

```
Twitter.sharedInstance().start(withConsumerKey:"yourAppKey", consumerSecret:"yourAppSecret")
```

You should also configure your Info.plist to include TwitterKit's URL Scheme like this:

1. In CFBundleURLSchemes you should have string key with this value
   "twitterkit-yourAppKey"
2. In LSApplicationQueriesSchemes you
       should add those "twitter" and "twitterauth"

For reference: https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/installation

PS: Make sure that "twitterkit-yourAppKey" in your CFBundleURLSchemes is Item 0, there is some weird bug in the current version (3.0.3) and if its not the first item it crashes.

Comment: The last part (make sure `twitterkit-{yourAppKey}` is item 0) did the trick for me, thanks!

Comment: The code they give you for Twitter.sharedInstance().start(... can't be copy pasted. You have to put your keys in manually. I had just copy pasted it without looking, and they had a fake key and secret set in the code examples.

Answer (score 0):

Like the answer above wrote, I was doing this and it crashed:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fbmykey</string>
            <string>twitterkit-mykey</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Then changed to this and it worked:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>twitterkit-mykey</string>
            <string>fbmykey</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```