# Twitter Login crash

Tags: twitter, twitter-login

I am developing an app with Twitter login. When I am checking Fabric, it doesn't contain Twitter login as it's no longer available via Fabric, so I am trying to implement it using Twitter Kit ([Twitter Kit Link](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/installation)). 
I have installed Twitter Kit on my app, when I am trying to run the app it crashes on

`Twitter.sharedInstance().startWithConsumerKey(<key>, consumerSecret: <secret>)`

Error: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Any solutions...

Answer (score 0):

try this code

add this gradle line in you project

```
compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.0.0'
```

Write in your Activity/Fragment

```
//Your Custom Button
          private ivTwitter;
         //Twitter Login Button
          private TwitterLoginButton ivTwitterMain;

          //init twitter
 TwitterConfig config = new TwitterConfig.Builder(this)
                .logger(new DefaultLogger(Log.DEBUG))
                .twitterAuthConfig(new TwitterAuthConfig(Const.CONSUMER_KEY, Const.CONSUMER_SECRET))
                .debug(false)
                .build();
        Twitter.initialize(config);

        //find your button
      ivTwitter = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivTwitter);
      ivTwitterMain = (TwitterLoginButton)findViewById(R.id.ivTwitterMain); 

      //twitter login callback
      ivTwitterMain.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
                        // Do something with result, which provides a TwitterSession for making API calls
                        TwitterSession session = TwitterCore.getInstance().getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
                        TwitterAuthToken authToken = session.getAuthToken();
                        String token = authToken.token;
                        String secret = authToken.secret;

                        getTwitterUserProfile(session);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                        // Do something on failure
                        Log.d(Const.FRAGMENT_REGISTER, exception.getMessage());
                    }

                });
```

getTwitterUserProfile code

```
private void getTwitterUserProfile(TwitterSession session) {
        AccountService accountService = new TwitterApiClient(session).getAccountService();
        Call<User> callback = accountService.verifyCredentials(true, true, true);
        callback.clone().enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<User> result) {
              Log.d("NAME ", result.data.name);
               Log.d("EMAIL", result.data.email);
              Log.d("PICTURE ",  result.data.profileImageUrl);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {

            }
        });
    }
```

at last generate Click event of custom button

```
ivTwitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //twitter login button
                ivTwitterMain.performClick(); 
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have already read the twitter official documentation about "Installation" of the TwitterKit in iOS app. I had such experience and the only thing that worked and wasn't in the documentation was this:

- In your Info.plist file make sure that "twitterkit-yourAppKey" in
  your CFBundleURLSchemes is Item 0.

I've answered this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44427713/twitter-sign-in-crashes-with-twtrinvalidinitializationexception/). Hope it helps you :)